# python create string variable based on a another string variable (contains)

Tags: python, pandas, contains, data-manipulation

I have a messy string variable containing stage information, I want to create a cleaner string with fewer groups. The current dataframe looks like this:

```
cohort = pd.DataFrame({'stage_group': ['XXX Stage I', 'Stage II XXX', 'Stage III XXX', 'XX Stage IV XXX', 'NA']},index=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

My ideal variable is 3 levels: Stage I-III, Stage IV and unknown:

```
cohort2 = pd.DataFrame({'stage_group': ['XXX Stage I', 'Stage II XXX', 'Stage III XXX', 'XX Stage IV XXX','NA'],'stage': ['Stage I', 'Stage II', 'Stage III', 'Stage IV', 'Unknown']},index=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

I tried the following codes but they did not assign group correctly (I just got Stage I-III and unknown). Any suggestions would be helpful.

```
searchfor = ['Stage I', 'Stage II', 'Stage III']

cohort['stage'] = pd.np.where(cohort.stage_group.str.contains('|'.join(searchfor)), "Stage I-III",
                  pd.np.where(cohort.stage_group.str.contains('Stage IV'), "Stage IV", "Unkown"))
```

Comment: See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
"Did not work" and "any suggestions?" are not problem specifications.
Show us what you *did* get, and include code to reproduce the problem.  That way, someone can provide you with a tested solution.

Comment: what means "did not work"? Show what you get or create code which we could run to see it.

Comment: when I made code with your data and code then it works correctly - except last data because it has `V` instread of `IV`

Comment: I see problem only because `Stage IV` contains also `Stage I` so you should first check `Stage IV` and later `Stage I`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code works for me if I change order because `Stage IV` contains also `Stage I` so  `Stage IV` has to be checked before `Stage I`

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'stage_group': '''XXX Stage I 
Stage II XXX
Stage III XXX
XX Stage IV XXX
NA'''.split('\n')
}

cohort = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(cohort)

searchfor = ['Stage I', 'Stage II', 'Stage III']

cohort['stage'] = pd.np.where(cohort.stage_group.str.contains('Stage IV'), "Stage IV",
                  pd.np.where( cohort.stage_group.str.contains('|'.join(searchfor)), "Stage I-III", "Unkown"))

print(cohort)
```

Result

```
       stage_group
0     XXX Stage I 
1     Stage II XXX
2    Stage III XXX
3  XX Stage IV XXX
4               NA

       stage_group        stage
0     XXX Stage I   Stage I-III
1     Stage II XXX  Stage I-III
2    Stage III XXX  Stage I-III
3  XX Stage IV XXX     Stage IV
4               NA       Unkown
```